# Excel 2010 - How to quickly add multiple hyperlinks to different cells

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel document in which I have to add multiple folder hyperlinks. The problem is that I have more than a thousand rows, and doing it manually will take ages.

In each row, cell `B` will contain a unique value, but containing the same word, like "name". I would like cell `Cnnn` to link to a folder
identified by cell `Bnnn`. This picture illustrates what I need:

[image: illustration of spreadsheet with hyperlinks]

Is there any quick way to add them (like drag and drop) or a miracle shortcut (besides <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)?

Comment: Are the folders all in the same directory? And how much does the order of the hyperlinks matter?  I'm thinking send a directory listing to a file and open it in excel.  Do a bit of text manipulation to make the foldernames into links and then copy the links to the correct spreadsheet.

Comment: By line i mean row yes. each cell will contain the same word like "name" but a different hyperlink and i am interested that cell A1 to link to folder A, B1 to folder B and so on. Please tell me if you need any mode info and thx for your help.

Comment: Right... and where does the hyperlink come from? Can you please provide some real examples. What is the value of Cell A1 for example? And what is the hyperlink to be?

Comment: What is the end goal?  1000+ links to folders seems like you may be trying to do something with excel that would be done better with another tool.

Answer (score 4):

I found that calculating the file path like this worked:

```
=Hyperlink("file:///" & "C:\...")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use =Hyperlink("path/" & a1 ) then copy it down. A1, B1 etc would include the extra but of the hyperlink that changes

Comment: I'm having problems with the "path" of the folder part, could you please help with that? thank you.

Comment: Either the full unc path if it's on a network e.g. \\server\dfs or the absolute Windows path C:\folder . I suppose ActiveWorkbook.Path in VBA might make it more portable if needed

Comment: Thank you, i will try that, but any other ideas will be useful.

Answer (score -1):

Copy and paste the folder file path into a brower (chrome). Then CTRL + A the brower page into  an excel document. This will hyperlink all the names. Then its just a matter of sorting